# shifting the last column in the dataframe to the first place

Tags: pandas, dataframe

While this question had relative answers, I couldn't find an efficient and robust way of doing it. I have to shift the last column in my data frame to the first without disturbing any of the other columns. How should I do this ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14):

```
cols = list(df.columns)
cols = [cols[-1]] + cols[:-1]
df = df[cols]
```

Comment: Forgot the `list`. Edited

Comment: this puts the column in the fifth place and not at the first when I ran this code snippet.

Comment: That's weird. This should work for any regular data frame. I can't help you out without further details then

Comment: Wait, let me post my notebook cloudlink.

Comment: Works as expected.